# Opengl float buffer

Tags: opengl

I'm writing my first ray tracer. I want to make it work in real-time.
I want to use opengl for display.
I want to write my screen to floating point buffer and display the buffer.
What extension and/or buffer type I need?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm writing my first ray tracer. I want to make it work in real-time.

Ambitious!

> I want to use opengl for display. I want to write my screen to floating point buffer and display the buffer.

OpenGL can read from float buffers directly, e.g.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, data);
```

But OpenGL may choose any internal format that matches your selection. GL_RGB internal format can be anything that can somehow store RGB data. You can be specific about what you want. For example GL_RGB16 tells OpenGL you want 16 bits resolution per channel. The implementation may choose to use 24 bits per channel, as this allows for 16 bit to be stored. But ultimately the implementation decides, which internal format it will be, based on the constraints you put upon it.

Floating point framebuffers and textures are supported in OpenGL through extensions `GL_ARB_texture_float`, `GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float`, `WGL_ARB_fbconfig_float`, but due to patent issues not all OpenGL implementations implement it (ATI and NVidia do).

Comment: I got confused by "But OpenGL may choose any internal format". Does it mean that I can't specify pixel format RGB or BGR?

Comment: @user742010: You can tell OpenGL which format the data is you're supplying to it. But OpenGL is free to choose internally whatever it sees bit best. It is possible to tell OpenGL which internal format you'd like to have. See my edit.

Comment: There is GL_ARB_color_buffer_float also. It cannot be displayed, but it'a valid alternative in the case float textures are not supported.